# yii2 framework - error 403 when using images

Tags: php, frameworks, yii2

community members! I would like to address to you here with what question: In Yii2 framework to use css styles and js scripts need to ask the so-called resource bundle that the application had the opportunity to use them. What to do with images? I do not understand how to access to use them..

This is what is meant by the resource kit: (This file AppAsset.php)

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
        'css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'css/bootstrap-social-gh-pages/bootstrap-social.css',
        'css/flexslider.css',
        'css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css',
        'css/justified-nav.css',
        'css/font-awesome-4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'scripts/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js',
        'scripts/jquery.flexslider-min.js',
        'scripts/modernizr.js',
        'https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js',
        'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js'
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

so, here it throws 403 error:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
    <img src="<?= Yii::$app->request->baseUrl ?>/img/logo2.png" style="width: 100%;">   
</div>
```

Comment: There is no need to add bootstrap there as separate css and js files since you have got `BootstrapAsset` already added as dependency. Status 403 means that server refuses to proceed with this request (Forbidden). Maybe folder permissions need to be set.

Comment: Yes, about bootstrap I understand it, correct. But how to open access to any directory with images? At the moment this app is on my local server.

Comment: What URL it shows in HTML source when using `<?= Yii::$app->request->baseUrl ?>/img/logo2.png`? Can you open this URL directly in browser?

Comment: `http://basic/web/img/logo2.png` - and this is the correct url

Comment: So if the address is correct AND you can access it directly in the browser that means it's not a problem with the asset and image, something else is the reason.

Comment: trying to directly open the file in the browser I get the error: 403 forbidden. I don't have permission to access..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check that `img` directory is in public `web` direcory (where the `index.php` placed). Your `web` direcory should look like this:

   assets
   css
   img
   index.php
   ...
2. Check access rights to `img` directory and `logo2.png` file. They must be readable for the web server. For linux you can run this command in yii root directory `chmod -R a+r web/img`